# Temas PHP E Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Vocês lembram que no *Orkut* tinha aquela opção de mudar cor, e a cor escolhida funcionava em tudo.

Então, eu li alguns artigos e vi que da para fazer isso com o SASS, porém não entendo de SASS e gostaria de saber como posso fazer isso com o PHP?

Sem utilizar uma porrada de `IFs`.

Comment: Você quer que o usuário possa mudar, é isso? Eu raramente usei o orkut, então nem tenho ideia se é isto que quer dizer, seria como o tema de cores do twitter para o usuário? Você quer que isso fique só visivel para o usuario ou o tal usuario tem um perfil e quer que este perfil mude de cor para qualquer um que acessar?

Comment: Isso, seria igual o tema do twitter, mais isso ninguém tem acesso o perfil é exclusivo para a pessoa, é um sisteminha que eu quero implementar que ela possa escolher a cor do navbar.

Comment: Então não é igual ao do twitter, pq o do twitter propaga para todos outros o seu perfil, neste caso fica mais simples, vou lhe adiantar, vai precisar escolher, entre salvar o tema no banco de dados relacionado ao usuário ou apenas na sessão do navegador do usuário, mas isso dependeria do que você já tem pronto.

Comment: Então Guilherme, não tenho nada pronto, eu consegui alterar o tema com o JS fazendo dessa forma [link]<button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pt-4 mt-4" onclick="document.getElementById('navbar').style.background = 'blue'">Azul</button> [/link] porém não sei se é certo ou se é certo salvar no bd isso, e como trazer essa informação

Comment: E o que teria de errado em salvar no banco? Poderia até mesmo ser um arquivo tmp relacionado ao ID de usuário, a questão não é o que é certo ou errado, a questão é o que você precisa.

Comment: Então, eu não sei como salvar isso no banco, é possível salvar isso no banco? um cmd javascript?

Comment: CMD e JS? Pra que isso? Web é HTTP, simplesmente salve no backend, seja banco, seja txt, seja session.

Comment: CMD é abreviando comando, ou seja eu criei esse button usando o OnClick para trocar a cor do navbar, minha dúvida é como salvar isso no banco de dados mysql e carregar isso, como eu consigo ?

Answer (score 1):

Crie várias versões do seu layout, com cores distintas:

- layout.azul.css
- layout.vermelho.css
- layout.verde.css

Depois, considerando que você possui a configuração do usuário persistida de algum modo, você poderá carregar o arquivo CSS referente ao layout que ele escolheu. Por exemplo, supondo que a cor que o usuário escolheu esteja na variável `$cor`, você pode fazer

```
<link href="layout.<?= $cor ?>.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Carregando, assim, o respectivo arquivo para aquele usuário.

Comment: Entendi dessa forma, porém como eu fugiria dos ifs??

Comment: @FábioStraliotiMartins Que `if`s?

Comment: No caso, eu criaria varias versões do layout certo? ai o usuario definiria nas configurações o que usar, um exemplo, rosa. você me mostrou pelo carregamento [codigo] <link href="layout.<?= $cor ?>.css" rel="stylesheet"> [/codigo], porém eu teria que fazer alguns ifs nos lugares que eu quero alterar a cor não seria?

Comment: Não, dentro do arquivo `layout.rosa.css` já teria todo o CSS configurado para a cor rosa. A única coisa é que assim teria que manter várias versões do seu layout, o que pode prejudicar a manutenção.

Comment: A manutenção seria tranquila, pois deixaria cor fixa, o modo de chamar essa função é que fica minha dúvida, pois por padrão terá o layout vermelho, a pessoa clicando no rosa mudaria para o rosa, porém teria que sobrepor o vermelho. A minha dúvida é, como chamar o layout rosa no lugar do vermelho? ou somente chamando pelo link ele irá sobrepor?

Comment: Será que fazendo um if na hora que a pessoa escolher ele irá sobrepor tudo?